# gdb compiled from source cannot find working directory: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, gdb

I compiled gdb 13.1 from source on RHEL7 successfully. But everytime I start it and if I run the `pwd` once started, I get:

```
Error finding name of working directory: Permission denied
```

If I start `gdbserver`, I get the same error and it exits instantly.

I cannot try running it as root (enterprise environment), but I shouldn't have to anyway. I have every permission on the directory in which I run gdb.

EDIT: Output of `strace -e file gdb --batch -ex pwd`:

```
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/fd", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
lstat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "..", O_RDONLY)
newfstatat(3, "bin", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(3, "..", O_RDONLY)
newfstatat(4, "x86_64.linux.2.6.glibc.2.17", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(4, "..", O_RDONLY)
newfstatat(3, ".exec", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(3, "..", O_RDONLY)
newfstatat(4, "install", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(4, "..", O_RDONLY)
newfstatat(3, "13.1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(3, "..", O_RDONLY)
newfstatat(4, "gdb", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(4, "..", O_RDONLY)
newfstatat(3, "fsf", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(3, "..", O_RDONLY)              = -1 EACCESS (Permission denied)
gdb: warning: error finding working directory: Permission denied
...
lstat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "..", O_RDONLY)
newfstatat(11, "bin", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(11, "..", O_RDONLY)
newfstatat(12, "x86_64.linux.2.6.glibc.2.17", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(12, "..", O_RDONLY)
newfstatat(11, ".exec", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(11, "..", O_RDONLY)
newfstatat(12, "install", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(12, "..", O_RDONLY)
newfstatat(11, "13.1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(11, "..", O_RDONLY)
newfstatat(12, "gdb", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(12, "..", O_RDONLY)
newfstatat(11, "fsf", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(11, "..", O_RDONLY)              = -1 EACCESS (Permission denied)
Error finding name of working directory: Permission denied
open(".gdb_history", O_RDONLY)
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Please update your question with the output from `strace -e file gdb --batch -ex pwd`

Comment: Added the output of `strace`

Comment: In the directories where the GDB `pwd` command fails, does the GDB command `shell pwd` fail or succeed?

Comment: Aside from running `make` and `make install`, did you do anything else to this GDB? Any SELinux configuration, for example. Is it running in a container?

Answer (score 0):

> I have every permission on the directory in which I run gdb.

As is clear from `strace` output, you don't have read permission on `..` (parent) directory somewhere on the path leading to the `gdb` binary.

Your `strace` output is also mangled in some way: it should contain the return value of `openat`, but doesn't.

Comment: But why do I have to have every permission on every parent directory up to root? On other gdb versions we have in house, this problem doesn't appear.
Also the problem is not the path to the gdb binary but the path to the current directory from where I start it from. If I start it in /d/shared (a public mounted drive), no error appears.
I copied the trace by hand but I double checked, after the last openat, there's directly an error of "Permission denied" after it.

Comment: Also by the way, I do have the permissions on the directory on which it fails. I can read it, modify it (I own it). So why would gdb have a permission problem? If I understand correctly, for this path: fsf/gdb/13.1/install/.exec/x86_64.linux.2.6.glibc.2.17/bin, it's for the parent of fsf that it fails. But I do own that parent directory.

Comment: "But why ..." -- I don't know. There may have been a change to GDB which now requires this access. "I do have permissions" -- `strace` disagrees.

Comment: I can go to `fsf`, do `cd ..`, do `chmod 777 .` and have the same issue, on the same directory in strace.

Comment: @Percee It probably isn't the `fsf` directory, but `fsf/..` (or something above it).